# ParamConverter optional but valid

Tags: php, annotations, symfony

I'm trying to use a `ParamConverter` for an optional parameter

```
/**
 * @Route("/item", name="item_new")
 * @Route("/item/{id}", name="item")
 * @ParamConverter("item", class="AppBundle:Item")
 */
public function stepStockReceptionAction(Item $item = null)
{
    return new Response($item ? $item->getName() : 'New item');
}
```

My `$item` is now optional but if I give an invalid item id, it is simply considered `null`

```
GET /item/42 # <-- Non existant item
```

Gives

> New item

How can I have the default 404 error if the item does not exist ?

Comment: Haven't work with Symfony for a while but have you tried this: `@ParamConverter("item", class="AppBundle:Item", isOptional="true")`?

Comment: I suggest to spit the two route with different actions method (seems the have different responsibility)

Comment: @awons same behavior with the `isOptional` param

Comment: Same behavior, this actually validates the format but still allows a wrong id passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as said in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

> Several things happen under the hood:
>
> The converter tries to get a SensioBlogBundle:Post object from the
>   request attributes (request attributes comes from route placeholders
>   -- here id);
>
> If no Post object is found, a 404 Response is generated;

So no matter how you define Route and ParamConverter it will take `id` from request and try to find Item with this `id`. So you have 2 choices

1. split into two methods, one for create, one to other work with existing Item
2. use something like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/item/{id}", defaults={"id"=null}, name="work_with_item")
 */
public function stepStockReceptionAction(Request $request)
{
    $item = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->find($request->query->get('id')); 

    return new Response($item ?  $item->getName() : 'New item');
}
```